# Batch insert multiple records with Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-2.0, mongoid4

I am reading through [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772378/batch-insert-update-using-mongoid/3992570#3992570) about how to insert multiple documents in Mongoid in one query. From the answer I read:

```
batch = [{:name => "mongodb"}, {:name => "mongoid"}]  
Article.collection.insert(batch)
```

I need an example to understand how this works. Say we have the Article class:

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :subject,   type: String
  field :body,      type: String
  field :remote_id, type: String

  validates_uniqueness_of :remote_id

  belongs_to :news_paper,   :inverse_of => :articles
end
```

And the I e.g. create an array of articles:

```
[ {subject: "Mongoid rocks", body: "It really does", remote_id: "1234", news_paper_id: "abc"},
{subject: "Ruby rocks", body: "It really does", remote_id: "1234", news_paper_id: "abc"},
{subject: "Rails rocks", body: "It really does", remote_id: "5678", news_paper_id: "abc"} ]
```

How do I create them, and at the same time make sure the validation catches that I have 2 remote_id's that are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a unique indexing for `remote_id` field, MongoDB will take care the uniqueness of this field

`index({ remote_id: 1 }, { unique: true })`

Don't forget to run create_indexes: `rake db:mongoid:create_indexes`

After that, you are free to use `Article.collection.insert(batch)`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But where should `index({ remote_id: 1 }, { unique: true })` be put in. Is it into the model?

Comment: yes, see the doc for more details http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/indexing.html

Comment: Any idea how you create the indexes on the server. Locally, you can simply create the index from the terminal at your terminal location. But on the server it seems that I can't do it from `~/applications/myapp/current`.

Answer (score 0):

As Zakwan mentioned, create a unique index.

As of Mongoid 8 and Mongo 2.19, use `insert_many`

```
Article.collection.insert_many batch
```

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/