# How to perform a batch update using Mongoid without finding first?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have an array of hashes like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 123,
    color: 'red'
  },
  {
    id: 456,
    color: 'green'
  }
]
```

I know how to fetch and update one at a time:

```
params[:my_documents].each do |doc|
  MyDocument.find(doc[:id]).update_attributes(color: doc[:color])
end
```

…but I suspect that the performance is not very good. I'd like to find a way where I can pass the data to Mongoid/MongoDB directly so that I can update each document without having to find and instantiate every document in order to update a few fields.

How can I perform a batch update using Mongoid without having to fetch them first?

Comment: No, the point is that I know the `id` of all the documents I want to update, and I need to update multiple documents, so I want to find a way to pass the data and have it perform as one efficient transaction rather than sequentially fetching and updating one document at a time.

Comment: Is there some reason this is not a duplicate? You seem to be saying you already know all the data you want to insert. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772378/batch-insert-update-using-mongoid

Comment: Actually nope it isn't your talking about updates

Comment: Not really an answer, but wait for the 2.6 release: http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/command/update/#dbcmd.update

Answer (score 1):

The mongo-ruby-driver version 1.10 (gem 'mongo', '~> 1.10.0') supports bulk write operations. For your example, a batch of updates can be submitted as one request for significant performance gains when used with a 2.6 MongoDB server.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/Bulk-Write-Operations

Bulk write operations are not yet available in Mongoid but are planned for a future release based on a new version of the "mongo" Ruby driver.

Comment: its still not there ... i am using mongoid 5