# Mongoid batch collection insert: how to get the ids of the newly created items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, bulkinsert, mongoid4

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3992570/297471), it's fairly easy to batch insert an array of new documents into a MongoDB collection:

```
batch = [{:name => "mongodb"}, {:name => "mongoid"}]  
Article.collection.insert(batch)
```

What I don't find easy though is how to retrieve the list of newly created ids. Is it possible to code something like:

```
batch = [{:name => "mongodb"}, {:name => "mongoid"}]
result = Article.collection.insert(batch)

result[:ids] # not real code
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @muistooshort Nope. I'm inserting up to millions of items (in batches of 5k) and I can't afford querying for them after each insert.

Comment: I'm not inserting them explicitly, but it seems like mongoid prefills those in the `_id` field when you `create` an object (not like in the example); so if you collect them before the actual bulk insert and this one is successful, you can say you've got them. I'll test the thing and write an answer to this question.

Comment: did you test, i want to batch insert as well... i have parent and child objects of parent, i want save with association in batch save

Answer (score 0):

You can now access this data with inserted_ids https://www.mongodb.com/docs/ruby-driver/master/api/Mongo/BulkWrite/Result.html so for your example it would be

```
batch = [{:name => "mongodb"}, {:name => "mongoid"}]
result = Article.collection.insert_many(batch)

result.inserted_ids
```