# Batch insert documents on mongoid relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have read the answers here on batch insert e.g. [batch insert mongoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772378/batch-insert-update-using-mongoid)

I have 2 collections:

```
 class User
  include UpdateUserOrCreate
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_many :messages, class_name: "Api::V1::Message", autosave: true, validate: false
  has_many :message_export_requests, class_name: "Api::V1::MessageExportRequest", autosave: true, validate: false
end

 class Message
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  belongs_to :user, class_name: "Api::V1::User", autosave: true, foreign_key: :user_id 
end
```

I have a document array :

```
batch = [{name: "dsfdf" },{name: "dfsdfh"}]
```

I am trying to do:

```
user.messages.collection.insert(batch)
```

But the result is that the Message documents are saved with user_id = nil.

How can I batch save the documents in the array through the relation making sure that the foreign key is set??

Comment: what is this messags in user.messags.collection.insert(batch) ?

Comment: @Krish `user.messags`  is a typo and should read `user.messages`  and its the has_many relationship between User and Message. `batch` is just a document array that holds valid documents

Comment: ok , that user.messages is a User or user object? can you put here the detailed log and all?

Comment: user is an instance of User. user.messages is the ( I suppose) the relation object. The log for the operation `user.messages.collection.insert(batch)`  is : _{"connectionId"=>2, "n"=>0, "syncMillis"=>0, "writtenTo"=>nil, "err"=>nil, "ok"=>1.0}_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
user.messages.create(batch)
```

Also in your case you need to add this to the Message model:

```
field :name
```

**=== UPDATE ===**
Perhaps this could be useful:

```
user = ... # get user somehow
batch = [{name: "dsfdf" },{name: "dfsdfh"}].collect { |msg| {name: msg.fetch(:name), user_id: user.id} }
Message.collection.insert(batch)
```

Answer (score 0):

`collection` returns the driver's collection object. The driver has no knowledge of Mongoid models. You need to set the association links explicitly:

```
batch = [{name: "dsfdf", user_id: user.id },{name: "dfsdfh", user_id: user.id}]


user.messages.collection.insert(batch)
```