# Mongo::Collection undefined method `insert'

Tags: mongoid

I'm trying to import millions of rows from another database into MongoDB. My routine for import uses

```
MyModel.collection.insert(data_to_import)
```

And I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `insert' for #<Mongo::Collection:0x000000082bb990>
/home/mika/projects/ca2/lib/tasks/data.rake:36:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

The model is defined with

```
class MyModel
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

end
```

Does anyone have any suggestions about what is happening?

I can save the rows one by one but that is so inefficient for millions of rows. Would like to get the insert to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using mongoid5 use

```
MyModel.collection.insert_many(data_to_import)
```

if data_to_import is an array or

```
MyModel.collection.insert_one(data_to_import)
```

if data_import is a single document

also consider using MyModel.create if you need valdating the data...

Comment: Thanks. With insert_many it is adding new documents but they are added one by one. At least each insert is logged separately. But well, 10k documents takes a few seconds to import, so it is pretty good. And I don't know if MongoDB has a real bulk insert.